An answer in a comment was converted to an answer — why are flags that say the comment is no longer needed being declined?
I recently converted this comment to a community-wiki answer. I flagged the comment as not being needed, explaining it had been converted word for word into a community-wiki answer. The flag was declined.
When I have done this in the past, I have flagged the associated comment as being no longer needed, or with a custom moderator message explaining the conversion to an answer. These flags to remove the now-obsolete answer-in-a-comment have always, until now, been accepted, resulting in the deletion of the source comment(s): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and ten others, but you get the idea.
Moderators: can you please explain the change in approach?

As the reference is a link to the comment without mentioning the author, I think it would be problematic here to delete the comment as it makes the reference meaningless.
It may well be I overlooked this detail in the past.
